# Convertir .odt a texto plano en C#

Tags: c#, .net

¿Hay alguna manera de convertir un archivo de OpenDocument ( odt,ods, odp) a texto plano en C#?

Llevo días buscando y no he encontrado nada que sea gratuito.

Comment: Mira este [programa](https://github.com/dstosberg/odt2txt)

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar una librería que permita acceder a la información de este documento:
http://opendocumentformat.org/developers/

Como verás en la sección, hay varias que puedes usar, como ser `ODF.net` o `Aspose.Words`. Con estas librerías podrás acceder al contenido.

Puedes referenciar estas librerías usando nuget:
[ODF .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Independentsoft.Office.Odf/)

Tiene muchos ejemplos para aprender a usar la librería.

[odf tutorial](http://www.independentsoft.de/odf/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Sí, ya la estuve mirando, pero la versión gratuita tiene limitaciones..